# Plot multiple line graphs on the same window with auto-assigned different colors

Tags: r, plot, colors, linegraph

I want to create a vector of functions with two parameters where one parameter is over a continuous range of values and the other runs over a fixed number of numerical values saved in the column vector `dat[,2]`.

```r
# Example functions
icc <- function(year, x) {
  z = exp(year - x)
  inf = z / (1 + z)
  return (inf)
}

# Example data
year <- seq(-4, 4, 0.1)
x1 <- dat[1, 2]
x2 <- dat[2, 2]

# Plots
plot(t, icc(year, x1), type = "l")
plot(t, icc(year, x2), type = "l")
```

The issues are

1. `dat[,2]` has more than just 2 values and I want to be able to plot all the corresponding functions on the same plot but with different colors
2. manually assigning colors to each line is difficult as there are a large number of lines
3. dat[,1] stores the corresponding label to each plot; would it be possible to add them over each line?

I have something like this in mind-
[image]

**UPDATE:** `dat` is simply a 40 x 2 table storing strings in the first column and numerical values in the second. By 'a vector of functions', I mean an array containing functions with parameter values unique to each row. For example- if `t^i` is the function then, element 1 of the array is the function `t^1`, element 2 is `t^2` and so on where t is a 'range'. (Label and color are extras and not too important. If unanswered, I'll post another question for them).

Comment: It is currently difficult to understand your question because (a) we do not have access to `dat` or `dat2`, (b) it's not clear what you mean by a "vector of functions with 2 parameters where...the other runs over a fixed number...saved in `dat2[,2]`." You'll need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Additionally, your question title asks for how to automatically assign different colors to each line in your graph. However, in the body you ask for how to put a label over each plot and other questions. 1 question per.

Comment: @socialscientist Updated the question to answer these!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to use is `matplot`, not `plot`. There is also `matlines` but if the data to be plotted is in a matrix, `matplot` can plot all columns in one call.

1. Create a vector of y coordinates, `yy`, from the x values. This is done in a `sapply` loop. In the code below I have called the x coordinates values `xx` since there is no `dat[,2]` to work with.
2. Plot the resulting matrix in one `matplot` function call, which takes care of the colors automatically.

The lines labels problem is not addressed, only the lines plotting problem. With so many lines their labels would make the plot more difficult to read.

```r
icc <- function(year, x) {
  z = exp(year - x)
  inf = z / (1 + z)
  return (inf)
}

# Example data
year <- seq(-4, 4, 0.1)

xx <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2)
yy <- sapply(xx, \(x) icc(year, x))
matplot(year, yy, type = "l", lty = "solid")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Note

Function `icc` is the logistic distribution CDF with location `x` and scale 1. The base R `plogis` function can substitute for it, the results are equal within floating-point precision.

```
icc2 <- function(year, x) plogis(year, location = x, scale = 1)

yy2 <- sapply(xx, \(x) icc2(year, x))
identical(yy, yy2)
#> [1] FALSE
all.equal(yy, yy2)
#> [1] TRUE
```